# What connectors are these and how do I disconnect them?

Tags: connector

I am having difficulty disconnecting two different connector-types and I am hoping someone can help me either specify which type of connectors this is or just simply how to disconnect them.

Thank you so much in advance for any help, se pictures below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally you would just pull ...

Comment: Check carefully if there are any plastic 'latches'. (Little plastic hooks between the connectors) They are normally very visible except if they are between the connector and the PCB. A magnifier and a bright torch might help. If not, all that is left is "wiggle and pull".

Comment: In some cases you can put a flat blade screwdriver in a rectangular gap and rotate it to avoid damaging the board mounted side.

Answer (score 2):

Do not just pull. there are little latches that hold them in place. you need to make sure these are released either with a small flat screwdriver or the right pressure on the housing then pull.
[image]