# How do I disconnect connectors without resorting to brute force?

Tags: connector

I have the following circular connector.

[image]

[image]

I am wondering whether there is a way of uncoupling them without resorting to brute force, the reason why one of the red plastic housings is disconnected is from the aformentioned brute force. The reason is because I have to take apart some wiring and the connectors are attached to a flimsy button that I have taken effort in not damaging.

Based on [other similar questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392616/what-connectors-are-these-and-how-do-i-disconnect-them) I have attempted to look for interactable tabs such as screws, to no success. The closest thing to a tab is a circular popup (very light popup) thing that lightly snaps through a hole of the connector.

So far, I have attempted to use a careful amount of force (due to the button issue), as well as wiggle the connector with my hands. Also, I have not been able to push down the popup, with fingers or a screwdriver.

Please let me know if more information/pictures is required.

Comment: Grab the metal with pliers, wiggle side to side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though, this seems like tool assisted brute force. I have been attempting to wiggle it with my hands to limited success. Thanks for letting me be aware I should specify my attempts at disconnecting the connectors.

Comment: Your hands are no meaningful comparison. They are big and squishy.

Comment: Also that is two females bridged by a male-to-male. You can just cut the male in half then grab that with pliers and yank it out or wiggle side to side. Then replace it. Grab the metal at the neck or the flats. Don't grab and crush the curved part or it gets tighter.

Comment: Sometimes there is a very small tab that snaps into a small hole in the face of the mating connector. It's something you might easily miss. A dental pick or similar pointed instrument can be used to push the tiny tab so that it no longer interlocks with the hole. This will allow the connectors to disengage with less force

Comment: @DKNguyen That isn't a male-to-male connector.  The male connection is part of the left hand receptacle.  Doesn't make much difference, just thought I would point it out.

Comment: @HandyHowie That's weird. So is the left hand side a dual gender connector?

Comment: as Mathkeepsmebusy points out, the little tab in the middle is easy to miss. I sometimes use a needle-nosed pair of pliers to separate this type of connector. Grab the female half-way down the middle, which avoids crushing the round bits, then tip the pliers back and forth until one tip engages with the little tab. However, from your picture, it looks like that tab is much smaller than usual and might not engage that way. As it's small, brute force might be your only option.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes.  Usually the male part is bent backward allowing a second receptacle to be connected to the same terminal.

Comment: Those are not circular connectors. They are 1/4" tab connectors, often called "Faston(tm)" crimp terminals.

Comment: Also called "spade" connectors. The round part is a crimp connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific tool that I'm aware of outside of something that you'd find in a toolbox. The methods I've used are to try and find things to jam inbetween the connectors and pry them apart, usually pliers or screwdrivers.

This can be a big problem if the connectors are corroded or the connectors are jammed because of improper crimping.

It might be easier to just cut them and install new ones.

Answer (score 3):

What I do with these if they're tight is use a pair of small needle-nosed pliers, lightly hold the area between the two connector halves with the pliers and twist the pliers sideways so they act as a lever between the two halves, pushing them apart.

The little plastic insulator should pop right back on.